# How do I single out one item in an array of objects, then iterate through the rest?

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Goal:** In the end I want to display every object in the array, but I want to single out one of them (the first one or a random one) so that it will have a different class from the rest of the group.

**Problem:** `each` iterates through everything, stopping for nothing. `with` holds the entire thing. What holds just one thing?

The page/route I'm working with is subscribed to one big item, and in it sits something like this:

```
"colors": [
    { "shortName": "blue", "trueName": "Sky Blue" },
    { "shortName": "red", "trueName": "Blood Red" },
    { "shortName": "white", "trueName": "Crystal White" }
  ]
```

I want to display each of them on the page, and I do this right now the regular way:

```
{{#each colors}}
  <div class="{{shortName}} hidden">{{trueName}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Now, I want to only display one color at time, and I want to achieve this by adding the class ´hidden` to all but one. It doesn't matter which is singled out, just that something is.

Problem is, different items have different colors, so I can't set for example `white` outside the loop and not add the class `hidden` to it. `white` might not exist. Besides, if I did that, it would add `white` twice.

I feel this, as usual, is ridiculously simple but I'm whooshing on it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if/else block to handle each element of a collection in one of two ways, i.e. show it or hide it.

```
{{#each colors}}
{{#if shortName===selected_color}}
  <div class="{{shortName}}">{{trueName}}</div>
{{else}}
  <div class="{{shortName}} hidden">{{trueName}}</div>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This can be made less repetitive, by moving the if/else into the options for div in a single element.

Meteor also typically provides jQuery, and you could use that to single out a group of elements and apply hidden to all except one.

Comment: What should `selected_color` be then?

Comment: Problem with jQuery is that I also need the data inside the object to do additional stuff with.

Comment: "blue","red", or "white" or a variable containing one of those.

Comment: But I don't know if any of those colors will be available. That's the problem.

Comment: Ah, then you need to write a function that produces a list of the choices, possibly using `Collection.find` and some processing.  Maybe that is a new question.